# Htaccess Revert URL Encoding

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Facebook, and twitter rewrite urls and replace characters(like ? or /) with code.

Original URL - http://example.com/article.php?title=hi/how-are-you?

URL after(social network redirect): http://example.com/article.php?title=hi%2Fhow-are-you%3F

I use a hosted comment system(Disqus) which uses the URL as the thread identifier, which means I will get two threads for one page because of this variation.

Is there anyway that I can revert the characters through htaccess or another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the right line back with php-function:

```
$_GET['title'] = urldecode($_GET['title']);
```

So you can pass all urls thorough some rewriter.php with this function via .htaccess.
.htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rewriter.php [QSA]
```

rewriter.php:

```
<?php 
    $_GET['title'] = urldecode($_GET['title']);
    include('index.php');
?>
```

This method allows to use some statistics, redirects or other manipulations.

Comment: I would highly advise against this. Concerning register_globals: "This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged." http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: Of cource you're right, I'm very sorry. "php_flag register_globals on" can be removed from this code without any problems

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`rawurldecode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php).

Comment: Im not sure if I understand your answer. I know that this will decode the url as a string, but I need something more like a redirect that decodes the url dynamically - or are you suggesting something that is obscure to me?